# Rails: Update parent record, when Child get's saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Structure: An `Order` `has_many` sales (and a `Sale` `belongs_to` an `Order`).

- Each sale has a `quantity` and a `price` column.
- Each Order has a `totalprice` column

The `totalprice` is composed by `price` x `quantity` x `12`  out of the sales records that belonging to the parent `Order`.

This is how my calculation looks inside the Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :calc

  def price
   sales.to_a.sum { |item| item.price }
  end

  def totalpricex12
   totalpricex12 = price*12
  end

  def totaldiscount
   sales.to_a.sum { |item| item.discount }
  end

  def calc
   calc = (totalpricex12.to_f)-(totaldiscount.to_f)
   self.update_columns(totalprice: calc)
  end
end
```

**The problem is:** `totalprice` only gets updated, when the `Order` gets updated or saved, but not if a new `Sale` gets added or deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses):

```
#app/models/sale.rb
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :sales
   validates  :order, presence: true

   after_create  :update_order
   after_destroy :update_order

   private

   def update_order
      order.calc
   end
end

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sales, inverse_of: :order
end
```

This will give you the respective objects associated to `sale` / `order`, which will be made available through the [`inverse_of` method](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations):

> When we call `criminal.prison` without `:inverse_of` on both the `:belongs_to` and `:has_many` associations, it will hit the database. With `:inverse_of`, if we already have that prison record in memory then `criminal.prison` will point to the same prison.

Comment: Great Thank you. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`after_save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback, for example like this:

```
class Sale < ... 
  belongs_to :order

  after_save do
    order.calc
  end
end
```

of like this:

```
class Sale < ... 
  belongs_to :order
  after_save :update_order

  def update_order
    # call parent to self-update or something like this
  end
end
```